# How to write a DOS script to extract all the file name in a directory?

Tags: dos

I want to extract all the names and path of the file in a directory and its sub-directory into a text file. How can I do it by DOS scripting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dir * > t.txt
```

Or some other parameter to get your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with the dir command in in the windows-console

```
 dir /B /S /O > mylist.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dos batch programming you could use:

```
dir /B [fullpathtodirectory] > output.txt
```

to extract the list of the files in the specified direcotry.

With WSH (Windows Scripting Host) you can use the more powerfull FSO (File System Object):

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oStartFolder = "[full path to initial folder]"

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(oStartFolder)

Set Files = oFolder.Files
For Each oFile in Files
    'do stuff here
Next
```